# Angular dynamically add a fieldset with and input and button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to have a form, which has an input field taking numbers (15,30,45), which will be used as minutes. It is supposed to have an add button, which will add another row of that input with that add button beside it aswell. If I have more than one of those fieldsets, then I want to have a button besides all fieldsets, that can delete the input.

```
<div id="minute">
  <label for="MinuteImput">In Minute </label>
  <input type="number" id="MinuteImput" min="0" max="45" step="15">
  <button>+</button>
  <button *ngIf="count divs with id minute > 1" >-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you need a dynamic form

Comment: thank you, i will take a look at it

Comment: looks like a wrong condition in ngif

Comment: @SaeedSharman yes, it was supposed to be pseudo code to show my intention

Answer (score 0):

In Angular framework try to avoid using "id" itself. The theme of this framework is data binding. For your case you need to use "ngFor". Something like following.

```
<div *ngFor='let num of inptFieldArray'>
  <label for="MinuteImput">In Minute </label>
  <input type="number" id="MinuteImput" min="0" max="45" step="15">
  <button (click)="inptFieldArray.push(inptFieldArray.length)">+</button>
  <button *ngIf="inptFieldArray.length> 1"  (click)="remove(num)">-</button>
</div>
```

[Reference](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)